# How to call an outside function from button in cell

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I use a main class call `newsFeedCointroller` as `UICollectionViewController`.
1. In cell inside I have a newsfeed with a like button (to populate the cell I use a class called "FeedCell")
2. Out from cells (in mainview) I have a label (labelX) used for "splash message" with a function called "messageAnimated"

How can I call the "messageAnimated" function from the button inside the cells.

I want to to change the label text to for example: "you just liked it"...

Thanks for helping me

Comment: can you put some code for where is your 'button' and where is your function 'messageAnimated'

Answer (score 3):

In your FeedCell you should declare a delegate (Read about delegate pattern [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html))

```
protocol FeedCellDelegate {
    func didClickButtonLikeInFeedCell(cell: FeedCell)
}
```

In your cell implementation (suppose that you add target manually)

```
var delegate: FeedCellDelegate?

override func awakeFromNib() {
    self.likeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(FeedCell.onClickButtonLike(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
}

func onClickButtonLike(sender: UIButton) {
        self.delegate?.didClickButtonLikeInFeedCell(self)
}
```

In your View controller

```
extension FeedViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("feedCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeedCell
        // Do your setup.
        // ...
        // Then here, set the delegate
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }

    // I don't care about other delegate functions, it's up to you.
}

extension FeedViewController: FeedCellDelegate {
    func didClickButtonLikeInFeedCell(cell: FeedCell) {
        // Do whatever you want to do when click the like button.
        let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForCell(cell)
        print("Button like clicked from cell with indexPath \(indexPath)")
        messageAnimated()
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sory i'm new here, can you help me a little bit more (again, sory and thank you very much for helping me)

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1yGrYd6JFQU_xsqWEK_22H14nSTtc7TSUQxOFYtG-hp8/pub